# Singular value decompostion and operator norm

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, svd

Suppose that for $A$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ the singular value decomposition of $A$ is $UBV^T$ where $U$  $\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times t}$ and $B$  $\in \mathbb{R}^{t\times t}$ and $V$  $\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times t}$. If $W$ is a matrix in  $\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$  with $||W||_{op}$ $\leq 1$, $U^{T}W =0$ and $WV =0$, then, we are required to show that $||UV^{T}+W||_{op} \leq 1$.

I consider $U_1B_1V_1$, the singular value decomposition of $UV^{T}+W$ and I found two relations:

$UU^T +WW^T = U_1B_1^2U_1^T$  and $VV^T +W^TW = V_1B_1^2V_1^T$. But I think these relations just gives me  $||UV^{T}+W||_{op} \leq \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Note that $U^{\intercal}W^{2}V=0$

Comment: @xX A C E Xx , but I think we can't define $U^TW^2V$.